# Получить содержимое всех фреймов PHP + Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

Доброе время суток!

У меня есть задача: анимационный гиф необходимо обрезать и уменьшить до определенного размера.
Сложность в том, что мне после обрезки и уменьшения размера надо получить данные изображения в переменную, без сохранения на жестком диске. Код приведен ниже.

```
namespace Classes\Image;

class ImageResizer
{
    public static function resizeGif($path, $x0, $y0, $width, $height) {
        try {
            if(!file_exists($path)) {
                throw new \Exception('Gif file not exists');
            }

            $im = new \Imagick($path);
            $image = $im->coalesceImages();

            foreach($image as $frame) {
                $frame->cropImage($width, $height, $x0, $y0);
                $frame->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
                $frame->setImagePage($width, $height, 0, 0);
            }

            $image->deconstructImages();
            $image->writeImages('gif1.gif', true);
            $image->clear();
            $im->clear();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

ImageResizer::resizeGif('gif.gif', 150, 50, 220, 220);
```

Метод для получения всех фреймов найти не могу, сразу скажу что Imagick::getImage(), Imagick::getImageBlob() не работают, возвращают только первый фрейм.

Как получить содержимое анимации в переменную?

Answer (score 1):

Для решения этой задачи есть метод `Imagick::getImagesBlob()`, который возвращает все фреймы(всю анимацию).